# Remove nodes without a body in xslt

Tags: xslt

I want to find that nodes which have not a body using XSLT.

Input:

```
<p type="list_number_unn"/>
<p type="list_number_unn">
  <b>Text</b>
</p>
<p type="list_number_unn"/>
<p type="list_number_unn">
  <b>Text2</b>
</p>
<p type="list_number_unn">
  <b>Text3</b>
</p>
```

Desired Output :

```
<p type="list_number_unn">
  <b>Text</b>
</p>
<p type="list_number_unn">
  <b>Text2</b>
</p>
<p type="list_number_unn">
  <b>Text3</b>
</p>
```

I have no idea how to do this. I am using XSLT 2.0

Comment: Your input is not XML (no single root element). Also "body" is an ambiguous description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try It

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>    

    <xsl:template match="*[not(descendant::text()[normalize-space()])]" />

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @Xpathforlife Url: http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/?save=fb7b8e97-1de4-43c6-ba43-4832ba6cb858-xsltransformation

Comment: The problem with this pattern `*[not(descendant::text()[normalize-space()])]` is that if you are after not white space only text content the expression `*[not(normalize-space())]` will suffice, and if you want to select element "leaf" you would use `*[not(*)]`.

Answer (score 0):

**USE It**

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[not(descendant::text())]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```